# Given a collection of strings, can we make all the strings equal

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

The allowed operations are removal of character from a string and adding that character to another string. We can repeat the operation as many times as we want.

Given list = ['CAA', 'CBB'].
We can remove 'A' from the first string and add it to the second string.
'CA', 'CBBA'.
Now, we can remove 'B" from the second string and add in the middle of string 'CA'.
So, we have 'CBA' and 'CBA'

Answer (score 1):

**Step-1.** Compute the frequency of each character in all the strings of the list, let's say it as stringList.

**Step-2:** Compute the length of stringList and let's call it as length. (length is equal to the number of strings in the list.)

**Step-3:** Now, for the frequency of each character, Check if it is divisible by length. If any frequency is not divisible by length then it's not possible to equate the strings.

If it is possible:

Just distribute the characters equally among the strings to get an answer list.

Comment: in step-2, length should be equal to number of strings in the list.